# Int list to unit type

Tags: recursion, sml, ml

I am looking for a function `for : int * int * (int -> unit) -> unit`. I need this to print a list of numbers. To be more specific, I have a function `f num = print ((Int.toString num)^"\n")`. So far, I have this:

```
fun for(from,to,f)=
        if from=to then [f(to)]
        else f(from)::for(from+1,to,f)
```

which gives me a return type of `unit list`. How can I call for function without appending to earlier result?

Comment: use an internal function with an aggregator?

Comment: I tried that. You're still applying f to each numbers, and you're still appending to earlier result, thus giving unit list type. Or, did you mean something else?

Comment: I meant something like that: (I am not a pro in sml but it works the same way in all func langs):'fun forinner(from,to,f, acc)=
        if from=to then acc
        else forinner(from+1,to,f, f(from)::acc)'

Comment: and then your fun will be like: 'fun for(from, to, f) = forinner(from, to, f, [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `()` you want to return is the `()` from the last call to `f` - that is, the call from the `then` branch.

Generally speaking, whenever you want to do two things, and only return the result of the second thing, you use the following syntax:

```
(thing1;thing2)
```

For example:

```
(print "foo\n"; 2 + 3);
```

Would print out the string "foo\n", and then return `5`.

So now, let's look at the two branches of your code.

```
fun for (from,to,f) = if from = to 
                      then ...
                      else ...
```

In the `then` branch, we simply call `f` on `to`. `f` already returns `()`, so we don't do anything more with the result:

```
fun for (from,to,f) = if from = to 
                      then f to
                      else ...
```

The else branch is slightly more complicated. We want to call f on from, and then make a recursive call. The return type of the recursive call is `unit`, so that's what we want to return:

```
fun for (from,to,f) = if from = to 
                      then f to 
                      else (f from;for (from+1,to,f));
```

Another thing: What happens if you do this?

```
for (4,3,f)
```